# What is the difference between the two time formats?

Tags: python, datetime, time, assert, rfc3339

My goal is to use a single string time format (UTC).

I start with two string timestamps:

```
tf1 = '2020-07-11T17:25:48.675541+0000'
tf2 = '2020-07-11T17:25:49.125175Z'

RFC3339_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
```

When I assert if they both are in rfc3339 format, they both pass:

```
from datetiem import datetime

assert datetime.strptime(tf1, RFC3339_FORMAT)
assert datetime.strptime(tf2, RFC3339_FORMAT)
```

Why is that?

What is the difference between `tf1` and `tf2`?

More generally, what is wrong with my assertion here?

Comment: You need to have 3.8+ for 'Z' to be recognized as a valid timezone.  If you're on 3.7 or earlier, you'll get a ValueError and the format will not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%z` format specifier in `strptime()` accepts timezones in `±HHMM[SS[.ffffff]]` format, `±HH:MM[:SS[.ffffff]]` format, or `Z`, which is equivalent to `+00:00`. See note (6) in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

Note that this is not the same as [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6), which only allows `±HH:MM` or `Z`. Timezones without colons are ISO 8601 format.

Comment: So are you saying that RFC3339 does not precision beyond seconds?

Comment: RFC 3339 only allows time zones precise to minutes, not seconds or fractions of seconds. See the note in Section 4.2: **Following ISO 8601, numeric offsets represent only time
      zones that differ from UTC by an integral number of minutes.**

Comment: Okay got it. So my example works because of the answer you gave.
In this case what is the best way to represent time in a string which is precise to nanoseconds and has a time zone?

Comment: What's wrong with what you're using? The `%f` represents the microseconds.

Comment: My bad- I meant microseconds. :) I use %f. From your answer I understand that the `%z` format accepts both `+0000` and `Z` among other things. And as long as I present the time string in a `%z` accepted format, I can have flexibility over the time strings?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. `%z` is designed to allow flexible timezone formats.